# Let's Encrypt issue on Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean

Why Chrome labels my site "not Secure, but, IE and FF can load https site without any problem after installation of Let's Encrypt on apache/Ubuntu/Mysql?Wordpress on Digital Ocean. It is a brand new site and doesn't have any content. Any suggestion, please. Site URL: royalethnicwear.com

Answer (score 0):

Hm, try to force SSL with plugin Really Simple SSL. Link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change all the resource urls to https://

Change your site-url and home url. Now search for any http:// resource in source and change them https://

Hope this resolves the issue.